# Display an animation in Atom written in Octave

Tags: matlab, animation, octave, atom-editor

I have the following animation written in `Octave/Matlab`. I can display the animation in `Octave` or `Matlab` without problem when I run the code. As I mainly use `Atom` as text editor, I would like to display the animation from `Atom`. However, as I run the script in `Atom`, it only displays the last image of the animation (after having computed all the previous ones, but without displaying them).

Here is the code of an animation:

```
for i = 1:0.1:12; plot( sin( [1:0.1:12] + i ) ); drawnow; end;
```

Comment: interesting ... it seems Atom does not respect 'drawnow' instructions. Does this hold for all available graphics toolkits?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @TasosPapastylianou. To which other graphic toolkit are you referring?

Comment: octave supports the 'gnuplot', 'fltk' and 'qt' graphics toolkits. You can see which one you're running using the command `graphics_toolkit()`, or pass one of the above strings to set it explicitly (assuming it is installed and available).

Comment: Ok so `graphics_toolkit()` returns `ans = gnuplot`. What could be a next step?

Comment: First, try if a simple animation works, to exclude that. E.g. try: `for i = 1:0.1:12; plot( sin( [1:0.1:12] + i ) ); drawnow; end;` on the console, hopefully you should see a moving sinusoid. Second, see if you can change the graphics by doing `graphics_toolkig('fltk')` and try the sinusoid again. Also try with `graphics_toolkit('qt')` (I have a slight suspicion this may not be supported from within atom, in which case you'll just get an error message). If the simple sinusoid doesn't work with any of the available toolkits, I'd attribute this bug to atom specifically and ask at their forums.

Comment: thank you for your answer @TasosPapastylianou. So there is the same problem with the line `for i = 1:0.1:12; plot( sin( [1:0.1:12] + i ) ); drawnow; end;`. And indeed `graphics_toolkig('fltk')` and `graphics_toolkit('qt')` throws an error message

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou. I opened an issue on github (https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/18536) and I also put your example as MCVE instead of mine which indeed a bit long

Comment: Here is the answer I got from Github: "Thanks for reaching out! `However, as I run the script in Atom` Atom doesn't run code by default so I'm guessing you're having trouble with a community package? If that's the case, the Atom FAQ has information on how to contact the maintainers of any Atom community package or theme.

Comment: I don't use atom, so I don't know the specifics of how you're writing matlab / octave in it. From a cursory look, it seems that you must have installed an atom package like [language-matlab-octave](https://atom.io/packages/language-matlab-octave)? In which case, that's a reasonable suggestion to ask the person who wrote that package if they're aware of this bug and how to work around it ... though I suspect this kind of issue may be a bit over the maintainers head (but they may in turn ask for help in the octave community to resolve their package issue).